# with phpexcel how do I set column formats?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using an existing Excel file, with the first row containing plain text, to be used later as template. I then changed a few of the column formats to currency, accounting, date...e.t.c. Now I am loading in this file in phpExcel and populating data from my database to this file and saving it with a new name. But on the saved file, all cells in the newly created rows seem to be marked `general`, though the original plain text row still seems to have the correct format assigned.

My Code:

```
$xl_tmplt = ((isset($_REQUEST['excel_template']) && $_REQUEST['excel_template'] != "") 
    ? $_REQUEST['excel_template'] 
    : "report_tab1.xlsx");

require_once 'includes/classes/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';

$cacheMethod   = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array('memoryCacheSize' => '8MB');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

$tmp_workbook = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($tmp_folder_path . '/templates/' . $xl_tmplt);
$tmp_workbook->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$sheet = $tmp_workbook->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->fromArray($arr, '', 'A2');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($tmp_workbook, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($tmp_folder_path . "output/$filename");

$result['type'] = "success";
$result['msg']  = "The file was successfully created.";
```

Any idea how I can load in an excel file with predefined column formats and use it to generate a new excel? Or change/set the format of a column or cell range during generation?

PS: I am not too good with excel so I might have set the column format in the wrong way. basically I clicked on the column letter which selects the column, and then changed the format in the dropdown above. If this is wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please check below link for example of setting Row and Cell style

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/7333

UPDATE:
For formatting Numbers, Text, Date and Currency, please check below link

[PHPExcel Formatting](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/16178)

Comment: Thanks but I am not talking about `style` of cell, I want to change the `format` of cell.

Comment: I have updated the answer with possible formatting supported by PHPExcel (as per my knowledge)

Comment: @Amit - Can't understand the difference between format of a cell and style of a cell

Comment: I am not excel expert, but when you right click on any cell in excel and click "Format Cells", it gives options for Number Formatting, Borders, Fill, Protection etc. these all are available as Styles in PHPExcel. Please be specific about what you need so that I can help you

Comment: This does not answer the question. These are just links to work orders on php excel. Where is the example code? The answer should be code that allows you to format a cell within php excel.

Comment: Too bad you linked instead of answering the question here.  Now this response is useless.